# Complex Analysis Branch MultiValued

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

My attempt at the part a is above. I'm not sure how to show it is multivalued. Is it because the coefficient terms of the exponential are constant. So since we got 2 different values for argf on the first rotation then it will be a multi valued function

Comment: I don't get the "$[-1,1]$ branch cut". $f(z) = (z+1)\sqrt{z-1}$ and it has only one branch point at $z=1$ (the other being $\infty$) thus the branch cut has to be a curve from $1$ to $\infty$

Comment: @user1952009: It looks like a "red herring" to me. It surely confuses the student, making him believe that information important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Your argument seems correct. It also gives an indication of what to do.
The argument of the first term $(z+1)^2$ winds twice around as $z$ makes one turn. So it is in fact very easy (evident) to take a square root of that part. You then need to make some branch cut (from 1 to infinity) which allows for a definition of the square root of $z-1$.

Comment: Thank you,  I was just wondering is the answer to part (a) sufficient  as part (b) isn't a problem.  So when you say argument is correct do you mean my solution is sufficient or do you mean the argument of f is correct

Comment: I meant that your handwritten note explains well that the proposed solution is not single valued. You should perhaps make precise that you go around a circle of radius 2 (so as to avoid the proposed branch cut).

Answer (score 1):

Since $-1$ has been eliminated from $\Bbb C$, you may write

$$\left( \frac f {z+1} \right) ^2 = z-1 ,$$

and $\sqrt {z-1}$ is multi-valued for exactly the same reason for which $\sqrt z$ is multi-valued - namely, there are always *two* possible choices for the square root.

To make the above single-valued, choose the branch of $\sqrt {z-1}$ that in $z=2$ takes the value $1$ (the other possible choice would have been $-1$). With this choice, you will have $f(z) = (z+1) \sqrt {z-1}$ and, since $\sqrt {z-1}$ has become single-valued, so will be $f$ now. (Remember that in order for $z$ to be unable to make a full turn around $z=1$, you will also have to "cut" the plane along a curve going from $1$ to $\infty$ - for instance, a half-line.)